# Names of voice memos wiped after iOS8 upgrade - can I get them back?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, voice-memo

I finally upgraded to iOS8.1.1 on my iPhone 5 a couple of days ago. Everything seemed to be fine, but when I went to record something this morning, I noticed that *all* of my voice memos were just dated, rather than showing the name/label I'd given them.

I record a **lot** of voice memos for songwriting, melody ideas, rehearsals, etc. and have recordings going back to 2010, so knowing what they actually are is incredibly important.

I double-checked and it looks like all of my voice memos are backed up to my PC via iTunes with the original names intact. Is there anyway to get them back into Voice Memos on my phone, with those names, or will they just revert back to the dates again?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the free software [iBrowse](https://www.ibrowseapp.com/) to open your iPhone, then open the Recordings folder, and look for Recordings.db. This can be opened with [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). Open the DB in SQLite Database Browser, then Browse Data and find your filenames and their titles.

If they are not there, you could try making a new Voice Memo, and repeat this procedure. Now see if you can manually edit the DB to make the rest of your files match the format used to name the new Voice Memo. Ultimately save your .DB and copy it back to your iPhone using iBrowse. Make sure to save backups in case your iPhone doesn't like your hand-edited database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information - this was actually a really good idea. Unfortunately it looks like a) Recordings.db didn't store the custom titles for any voice memos, and b) it was last updated 27th November 2014 - which leads me to believe that iOS8 migrated away from using this file (as I've got a couple dozen new voice memos since then) and in the meantime, dropped the custom titles and is storing this info elsewhere. +1 for the tools though - good to know.